# Find number of combinations of strings

Tags: c++14

This was an interview question I was asked. My answer is below, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way. Possible a combinatorics type function, or is an exhaustive generation + count the only way?

Rules:
Given a character, the next character can be any one of 
How many N character combinations can you make?
For example

- a -> i,e
- e -> i,o
- i -> a,e,o
- u -> a,e,i,o
- o -> i,u,o

For N = 1 possible string combinations are
a , e, i ,o ,u

for N = 2 possible string combinations are
[ai, ae], [ei ,eo] ,[ia , ie , io],[ua,ue,ui,uo],[oi,ou,oo]

and so on.

I solved it by constructing a tree and then counting the leaves

```
struct Node {
    Node(char v) : v_(v) {}
    void                     add_child(shared_ptr<Node> n) { children.emplace_back(n); }
    char                     v_ = 0;
    vector<shared_ptr<Node>> children;
};

void add_child(shared_ptr<Node> root, int n, int depth, const map<char, vector<char>> &combo) {
    if (depth == n) return;
    auto ch = root->v_;
    auto it = combo.find(ch);
    for (auto ch : it->second) {
        //printf("Adding to %c to %c\n", ch, root->v_);
        root->add_child(make_shared<Node>(ch));
    }
    ++depth;
    for (auto &child : root->children) { add_child(child, n, depth, combo); }
}

int count_leaf(shared_ptr<Node> root) {
    if (root->children.size() == 0) return 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto &child : root->children) sum += count_leaf(child);
    return sum > 0 ? sum : root->children.size();
}
void password_combination() {   
    // Find combos until this depth
    int n = 3;

    map<char, vector<char>> combo;
    combo.insert(make_pair('a', vector<char>{'i', 'e'}));
    combo.insert(make_pair('e', vector<char>{'i', 'o'}));
    combo.insert(make_pair('i', vector<char>{'a', 'e', 'o'}));
    combo.insert(make_pair('u', vector<char>{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o'}));
    combo.insert(make_pair('o', vector<char>{'i', 'u', 'o'}));

    // Create a N depth tree and count leaves
    // Count all children until n = 3;
    auto root  = make_shared<Node>(0);
    int  depth = 0;
    for (auto &c : combo) { root->add_child(make_shared<Node>(c.first)); }
    for (auto child : root->children) { add_child(child, n, depth, combo); }
    printf("%d\n", count_leaf(root));
}
```

Is there a better way. Critique on the code/bugs, and if there's a c++14 idiomatic way of doing it, even better.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks @Barry  I'll post it there

Comment: I believe you could use recursion on the last letter of the 'word' without having to generate each word. That would be faster but not necessarily closed form.